# How to define whether datetime represents working or non-working day of NY Stock Exchanges?

Tags: python, datetime

How is it possible to check if given datetime represents a working or a non-working day of New York stock exchanges using Python? Non-working days can be either weekend or holiday or holiday-related days etc.

Comment: You'd probably want to write a function or something. I doubt anyone here is going to do that for you for free though.

Comment: Perhaps someone can suggest an API performing that task.

Comment: That's off topic here. There's a separate stack exchange site for software recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [holiday module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/holidays).
It allows you to check any date against holidays from different countries and returns a boolean value. It is also very customizable and should be able to accomplish everything you are asking for.

Comment: Neat module. Please don't encourage this sort of question though. There is a stack exchange site where both the question and this answer would be perfectly acceptable. It's just not SO.